# CKEditor RTL issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, ckeditor, arabic

I've added `language:'ar'`, `contentsLangDirection:'rtl'`, `contentsLanguage:'ar'` options to my CKEditor instance being initialized using the JQuery adapter. But the text is still left aligned.

It declares the `<html>` tag with `dir='rtl'` and `lang='ar'`, but on each `<p>` tag, it has an inline `text-align: left` style.

How do I get rid of that style?

Comment: in case you don't know elrte is CKEDITOR alternative ,  I had translated http://elrte.org/demo to arabic now and it should help you :)

Answer (score 5):

try this :

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            CKEDITOR.config.contentsLangDirection='rtl';
            CKEDITOR.replace('editorX');
        </script>
```